# If $a\leq b$ then $bc+1$ does not divide $ab$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Here is my problem:

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers such that $a\leq b$. Show that $bc+1$ does not divide $ab$.

First I thought I could show that $\frac{ab}{bc+1}<1$, but this is not necessarily. I am trying to express it as $\frac{ab}{bc+1}=x+\frac{p}{q}$ where $x$ is an integer and then show that $\frac{p}{q}\neq 0$, but I am unable to do so.

Comment: Well, anything that divides bc+1 can not divide b and vice versa.  So know none of the factors of bc+1 divide b so bc+1 dividing ab means bc+1 divides a which isn't possible if a < = b.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\gcd(bc+1,b)=1$$
so if $bc+1$ divides $ab$ then it divides $a$. Thus, there is $d\geq 1$ such that
$$a=d(bc+1)\geq bc+1>b.$$

(To prove that $\gcd(bc+1,b)=1$ note that if $p$ divides $bc+1$ and $b$, then it divides $bc$ and hence $p\mid(bc+1)-bc=1$.)

Answer (score 0):

If $bc+1$ divided $ab$, we'd have $\gcd(ab,bc+1) = bc+1$. But using properties of the gcd,
\begin{align*}
\gcd(ab,bc+1)
\quad\,\mid\;\quad&\gcd(a,bc+1) \gcd(b,bc+1) \\
=\quad &\gcd(a,bc+1) \gcd(b,1) \\
=\quad &\gcd(a,bc+1) \\
\le\quad &a \\
\le\quad &b \\
\le\quad &bc \\
<\quad &bc+1.
\end{align*}
So this cannot occur.